# Issues with removing a synced folder from Vagrant

Tags: vagrant

I am trying to remove a synced folder but with no Success.

I had a Vagrantfile like:

```
..
config.vm.synced_folder "/folder",
          "/vagrant/folder", default_sync_opts
..
```

but now I no longer have the folder 'folder', I tried just removing that line but it keeps trying to sync that folder.

I've also tried to add again that line and add the disabled : true option but it does not work. It still tries to sync. (plus it would be annoying to keep ever every folder I ever synced on Vagrantfile with disabled: true)

Anyone has gone through this/what can I do? I really don't want to vagrant destroy/vagrant up

Answer (score 0):

have you run `vagrant reload --provision`? It won't destroy your environment.

Comment: I've ran vagrant reload without --provision (did not work) as I did not want to reprovision it but I might give it a try.